# Open source interactive color theme chooser

Tags: javascript, css, themes

I would like to give my users something similar to [crystallines](http://demo.rockettheme.com/mar10/) color chooser or [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) so they can interactively theme the site.

Is there an open source solution that would go most of the way in this respect? Short of that what color picker would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

YUI color picker.

Ref:- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/colorpicker/colorpicker-fromscript.html